# DataTable not respecting overflow-y: scroll

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a page that has a container (div) with a jQuery DataTable inside it. The container has `overflow-y: scroll;` set on it, but for some reason, Firefox seems to be ignoring this. It works fine in Chrome. Here are screenshots:

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox]

Comment: This [codePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GPgyee) works fine in Firefox and Chrome... Post your code to reproduce the issue you have. No one can answer from only images.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out... Someone had put

```
<div class="">
  ...
</div>
```

around my container and I think firefox didn't like this div with an undefined class. Removing that fixed the problem.